# Merge replication - changes tracking level

Tags: merge, replication, change-tracking

I've got the following problem - I am replicating only selected columns from the table A. There are different updates performed at the publisher that update records in this table. There are many updates performed that affect only columns that are not replicated in the table A. However, in such cases, the replication engine decided that these rows must be also synchronized, because there was a change in a row. In my case, it is unnecessary and it has got a huge impact on the performance of the system. Is there any way to exclude those columns which are not replicated in the table A from the tracking changes mechanisms?

Thanks for all answers in advance. Peter.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using column level tracking for that table: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172023.aspx

Note that there is an overhead imposed for using column level tracking, so it must be weighed up against how much data is being sent to subscribers unnecessarily.

I hope that helped.